# KSH shell prompt overwritten

Tags: shell, ksh, prompt

I have customised my ksh shell prompt. It is as follows:

```
export PS1=$'\E[31;1m$(date +%H:%M:%S) \E[32;1m${PWD##*/} \E[33;1m$ \E[0m'
```

Sometimes when I press backspace the cursor will jump to the very beginning of the window and overwrite the prompt. I heard this can be a problem with escaping the colours however the examples I have seen online resemble what I have above.

Any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: This question might receive better answers if asked on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks, I posted there